# Collect Http metrics from Spring boot docker container running in AWS EKS

Tags: amazon-web-services, prometheus, amazon-cloudwatch

We need to collect http metrics from a Spring boot application running as docker containers in our AWS EKS cluster. Http metrics are only available as `/prometheus` endpoint in actuator. However there is no plan to use Prometheus as our monitoring service.

What ways are available to collect Spring boot docker http metrics into AWS CloudWatch?

Comment: Sorry if I'm completely missing something here, but isn't [this](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/containers/amazon-cloudwatch-prometheus-metrics-ga/) CloudWatch's own metrics scrapper?

Answer (score 1):

Using a cloud watch agent running on a host machine or in a sidecar container along with Spring boot Docker Container.